# Can't set SSH port to something other than 22

Tags: ssh, iptables

When I try to set my SSH port to something other than 22 (editing `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` and `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) I end up locked out of my server and having to boot into rescue mode to rectify the problem.

I've gone through this cycle a few times now, each time being more careful that I'm doing the right things.

Is it possible that my new port (33933 in this case) is somehow being blocked somewhere else - or there's another file referencing 22 that I need to change?

This is on CentOS 6 on a brand new dedicated box that I've just set up from oneprovider.com (an online.net reseller).

Comment: Is SELinux active? (`sestatus -v`)

Comment: Could you paste the output of `iptables -L -n -v` *into your question*?

Comment: So I did some googling, and one of the things that cropped up is that it's not recommended to set SSH to a port > 1024.  I tried the whole thing again with a port in that lower range, and it worked straight off.  Could it be that the hosting company knows SSH > 1024 is a bad idea and hence block it?  Seems unlikely.  Either way, my problem is fixed now, and I'm happy to be ignorant about why 33933 wasn't working - too much else to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set ssh to multiple ports. Just had multiple Port lines, eg

```
    Port 22
    Port 1500
```

That way you can can port 22 still working while you troubleshoot port 33933.

Next after you changed your config and restart ssh (you can restart ssh with an active connection), would be to test the server is listening on that port.

```
    netstat -ltnp
```

Post the output of that.

Comment: Great tip, I had no idea you could specify multiple ports - I'll certainly be doing that in future.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess that with CentOS it's SELinux blocking your connection. Try

```
selinux port -l | grep ssh
```

and see that probably only port 22 is allowed.

```
semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 39333
```

would add port 39333 to allowed ports for ssh. Verify with

```
semanage port -l | grep ssh
```

and you should be all set.

Comment: SELinux is disabled, good thought though.

Answer (score 2):

First question is, did you actually load the new configurations after you edited the files?

I would recommend setting up iptables to allow incoming connections on both ports as the first step. Secondly you can test an update to sshd without breaking your current ssh connection. If you type `service sshd reload`, you should be able to verify that you are able to start a new ssh connection, while keeping the old one alive, such that you can still revert your changes, if they do not work.

If you have `inetd` or `xinetd` installed on the server, you can use that to configure a secondary sshd port which operates independently from the primary. Here is an example of how that could look in xinetd:

```
service second-ssh
{
    type            = UNLISTED
    flags           = REUSE
    socket_type     = stream
    protocol        = tcp
    port            = 64739
    wait            = no
    user            = root
    disable         = no
    server          = /usr/sbin/sshd
    server_args     = -i
}
```

To find out if the other port is blocked somewhere on the network, you can use tcpdump on each end of the connection to see if the SYN packet is sent by one end and if it is received by the other end. If it turns out to be blocked, you can use traceroute to find out, where it is blocked: `traceroute -n -T -p 33933 example.com`

Answer (score 1):

After editing those files, you need to restart both services in order to apply the new configuration.

Just run `service sshd restart && service iptables restart` and you should be able to access.

Comment: I had tried both that and rebooting, neither was helping.